# xmlstarlet select a value in the path under <DataRecord id="4">

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I'm very new in using xmlstarlet and do not yet fully understand the syntax for selecting values. From a MBus-Meter I get telegrams in xml-format and I need to select some specific values. With

> xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//Value" -v . -n mbus-10.xml

I get all values, but I need to pick out the "Value" and the "Timestamp" in the path of

> DataRecord id="2"

In the example below it would be:
1450
and
2017-04-28T05:35:09

Can someone help me?

Here is the (abbreviated) xml-file:

```
<MBusData>
     <SlaveInformation>
        <Id>55993864</Id>
        <Manufacturer>DME</Manufacturer>
        <Version>64</Version>
        <ProductName></ProductName>
        <Medium>Heat: Outlet</Medium>
        <AccessNumber>134</AccessNumber>
        <Status>00</Status>
        <Signature>0000</Signature>
    </SlaveInformation>

    <DataRecord id="0">
        <Function>Instantaneous value</Function>
        <Unit>Energy (kWh)</Unit>
        <Value>273</Value>
        <Timestamp>2017-04-28T05:35:09</Timestamp>
    </DataRecord>

    <DataRecord id="1">
        <Function>Instantaneous value</Function>
        <Unit>Energy (kWh)</Unit>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <Timestamp>2017-04-28T05:35:09</Timestamp>
    </DataRecord>

    <DataRecord id="2">
        <Function>Instantaneous value</Function>
        <Unit>Volume (m m^3)</Unit>
        <Value>1450</Value>
        <Timestamp>2017-04-28T05:35:09</Timestamp>
    </DataRecord>

    <DataRecord id="3">
        <Function>Instantaneous value</Function>
        <Unit>Volume (m m^3)</Unit>
        <Value>231650</Value>
        <Timestamp>2017-04-28T05:35:09</Timestamp>
    </DataRecord>

</MBusData>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following approach:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//DataRecord[@id='2']/*[self::Value or self::Timestamp]" -v . -n mbus-10.xml
```

- `//DataRecord[@id='2']/*[self::Value or self::Timestamp]` - xpath expression, selects `Value` and `Timestamp` nodes which are the children of the `DataRecord` node with the `id` attribute value `2`
- `self` - axis containing just the context node itself

The output:

```
1450
2017-04-28T05:35:09
```